# How To launch a touchscreen Virtual keyboard during log in

Tags: yocto, touchscreen, window-managers, on-screen-keyboard

I am building an embedded linux OS for Allwinner's A20 cubieboard 2 using the yocto project. I have so far manged to build a core-image-sato for it which boots perfectly with lxdm login manager.

However, I would like to automatically launch an on-screen keyboard on the touchscreen every time a user is prompted for input, e.g during graphical login.

How do I go about that?

Where do I place a script to do that?

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

create a RC scripts rc5.d and make sure your script priority and it should run after all you rootfs processes.

I did not tested when the text box called keyboard on,
Better you need to call the keyboard functionality when ever the text box called.

```
this is according to you commet
```

1. open your text box and in command line use top command and check which process is called when text box opens.
   example:
   root@beaglebone$ top
   245  .. .. ..    text # this is process name for text box

   Then write script when ever text process is calling keyboard should on

Comment: Thanks, that is pretty easy to do.But I do not think that is the kind of  desired functionality.I want the on screen keyboard to be auto-launched every time user clicks on a text input box.

Comment: you mean when login time text box and keyboard both should call? then you need to make an app which is having keyboard and text box other wise see my answer may be it will helps you

Comment: Are you using Android or QT ?

Comment: It is a Qt based system.

Comment: good now you can see in tour board /usr/share/applications dir and read thos files then you will get an IDEA have any doubts come to discussin rooms

Comment: This just show the implementation of the apps on the desktop. Take for instance from the input methods, I have matchbox-keyboard.desktop.

Comment: The matchbox-keyboard.desktop file looks like this:

Comment: [Desktop Entry]
Name=Keyboard
Comment=Virtual Keyboard
Exec=matchbox-keyboard
Type=Application
Icon=matchbox-keyboard.png
Categories=Panel;Utility;MB
X-MB-INPUT-MECHANSIM=True
X-MB-SingleInstance=true
StartupNotify=true